# datetime.now returns wrong time if timezone changed after running interpreter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

### Background

I have an application with python scripts bound with C++ code via `boost::python` and have run into a problem that turned out to be reproducible with python interpreter.

### Problem

I have found that time returned by `datetime.now()` and timezone in `time.tzname` depend on the time the interpreter was run.

Steps to reproduce:

1. run interpreter (In my case it's 3.6.5)
   `python`
2. change timezone
   `timedatectl`
3. `import datetime, time`
4. `datetime.datetime.now()` and `time.tzname` return values that were valid before the timezone change

### Investigation

If the interpreter is run after the timezone change the values are correct. If I close the interpreter (not feasible in my original problem, the application has to run 24/7) and run a new one everything is ok.

It doesn't matter when I import the libraries, `importlib.reload()` doesn't help. `python2` (2.7.15) does not have that problem but I need python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `time.tzname` information is set once, when the `time` module is loaded. There is an explicit method in the `time` module to have it re-set, [`time.tzset()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.tzset):

> Reset the time conversion rules used by the library routines. The environment variable `TZ` specifies how this is done. It will also set the variables `tzname` (from the `TZ` environment variable), `timezone` (non-DST seconds West of UTC), `altzone` (DST seconds west of UTC) and `daylight` (to `0 if` this timezone does not have any daylight saving time rules, or to nonzero if there is a time, past, present or future when daylight saving time applies).

`datetime.datetime.now()` does not produce a datetime object with a timezone; you generally would pass in a timezone explicitly.